# How to visualize geodesics in Kruskal–Szekeres?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, geodesics

Consider the Schwarzschild metric
$$
ds^2 = -(1-\frac{2 M}{r})dt^2 + (1- \frac{2 M}{r})^{-1} dr^2 + r^2 d\theta + r^2 \sin^2 \theta d \phi^2.
$$
If we solve the geodesic equation
$$
\frac{d^2 x^a}{d\lambda^2} = \Gamma^a_{bc} \frac{d x^b}{d\lambda}\frac{d x^c}{d\lambda},
$$
where $\Gamma^a_{bc}$ are the christoffel symbols and $\lambda$ is some affine parameter.

We can nicely visualise the solution (in 3D) by plotting solution
$$
x^a = (t,r ,\theta,\phi)
$$
as a three-vector
$$
(r \sin \theta \cos\phi, r \sin \theta \sin \phi, r \cos\theta ).
$$
We can do this since for $M \rightarrow 0$ the metric reduces to Minkowski in spherical coordinates.

Now consider the Kruskal–Szekeres coordinates, where the line element takes the form
$$
ds^2 = \frac{32}{r} e^{r/2 M}(-dT^2 + dX^2)+ r^2 d\theta + r^2 \sin^2 \theta d \phi^2.
$$
We can again solve the geodesic equation and have the solution
$$
x^a = (T,X,\theta,\phi).
$$
But now It is not clear to me at all how to visualize the solution in a sensible way.
What vector should I plot and why?

Comment: In the same way as you would with Schwarzschild, but remembering that $r$ is a function of $X$ and $T$. The change of coordinates does not change the spherical symmetry.

Comment: The equations of motion in your coordinates are [here](http://relativity.yukterez.net/46.html#10e) at Output 10e where {T,X} is labeled as {u,w}